# Uso de DatagridView

Tags: datagrid

Mi pregunta es...En base a la siguiente imágen...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un Combobox (CB) y un Datagridview (DGV), al seleccionar un dato en el CB con un "Click" hago una búsqueda secuencial en el DGV, con eso no tengo problema (ejemplo1).

Mi necesidad es saber que método o como puedo emular por código el oprimir la tecla "ABAJO" (DOWN) o con el ratón oprimir Flecha-baja de la barra de desplazamiento vertical.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es por que la búsqueda la hago bien, sin embargo a veces no aparece visible en el espacio del DGV (ejemplo2), aunque se efectua la búsqueda con éxito. Pienso que dentro de la búsqueda debo emular dicho click.

Agradezco de antemano la atención prestada... Saludos

Comment: Buenas tardes, podrías mostrar el código que utilizas para poder ayudarte de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias raintrooper, pego el código

Answer (score 0):

Ma que pulsar la tacla ABAJO deberas establecer correctamente el foco en la fila deseada.

Con el siguiete codigo estableces el foco en la fila 10.

```cs
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    int filaASeleccionar= 10;

    dataGridView1.Rows[filaASeleccionar].Selected = true;
    //Foco celda 1
    dataGridView1.Rows[filaASeleccionar].Cells[0].Selected = true;
    //Foco celda n...
```

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo dbz, lo voy a aplicar...

Comment: De hecho lo probé, sin embargo a veces funciona y a veces NO, esto sucede cuando voy muy al final de la lista (datagridview) y busco un dato al principio de la lista...